If I create my custom tokens on Stellar network, and I want my clients to use it, where can I launch (an Exchange) and how can they buy?
I would like to launch my custom token, and I want a launchpad / Exchange for me to list / launch it.
Now the question is,

How friendly is Stellar for a financial institution ?

How can my clients across the world buy my custom token using their native currency / FIAT ?


Some of my clients have no / zero knowledge about wallets, public keys and all.
